# subquery returns more than one row mysql error

Tags: mysql

Help me to write query, select city name which is having vendor name greater than 2

```
ID   Name      City   emp_count  vendor
'1'  'Sprox'  'RAJ'  '23'       'es'
'2'  'Raj'    'RAJ'  '4'        'es'
'3'  'juli'   'BAN'  '4'        'bob'
'4'  'crafer' 'BAN'  '5'        'axe'
```

Query :

```
select city from test.org where 2= (select  count( vendor )from test.org group by vendor) ;
```

Comment: Luckily, the condition never arises.

Comment: @Strawberry, This is just the sample data. So this cond might met with the production data.

Answer (score 0):

What about this -

```
SELECT city, COUNT(vendor)
FROM test.org
GROUP BY city
HAVING COUNT(vendor) > 2;
```

Comment: It's worked with this SELECT city, COUNT(vendor)
FROM test.org
GROUP BY vendor
HAVING COUNT(vendor) >= 2;

Comment: You mentioned that you need vendor greater than 2. Not >= 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer first, What I meant is, you have written group by with city, But I need by vendor

Answer (score 0):

```
select city,vendor, count(*)
from t
group by city,vendor
having count(*) >= 2
```